# Installing and running Auto-Sklearn in Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, ubuntu, anaconda

I am trying to install Auto-Sklearn so I can finish my research on Auto-ML

I tried installing Virtual Box on my computer and use Ubuntu but it made my computer die.

So I had to find another solution

I found this page on how to install AutoSklearn on Windows 10

https://github.com/automl/auto-sklearn/issues/431

Being following this step by step still these issues stopped me

While installing AutoSklearn I got this error

```
ValueError: SMAC requires Python 3.4 or newer.
```

[image]

when I checked python version it was 3.6.7

Why am I getting this error??

another question,

I am using Spyder from Anaconda on my windows. can I still use that for AutoSklearn? i mean using bash on Windows will allow Anaconda access AutoSklearn??

if not then how can I use Python from bash??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got success installing auto-sklearn in Windows.

You should try this:

https://medium.com/@gracy.f/automl-for-python-on-windows-314ca8ea6955

Comment: Thanks. After step 4 I had to do the following: 1. sudo apt update && upgrade
2. sudo apt install python3 python3-pip ipython3. This page helps with that: https://medium.com/@rhdzmota/python-development-on-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl-17a0fa1839d